# Intel 13980HX reports 5.4 GHZ max instead of 5.6 GHZ

Tags: cpufreq, intel-cpu

I have a laptop with an Intel 13980HX which is supposed to have a max boost frequency of 5.6 GHZ on the p-cores.

However Linux is reporting max of 5.4 GHZ at the moment, any clues why? I'm running the OEM kernel 6.5.0.

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.5.0-1008-oem (buildd@lcy02-amd64-111) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #8-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Nov 10 13:08:33 UTC 2023

cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 183
model name  : 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13980HX
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x11d
cpu MHz     : 1612.499
cache size  : 36864 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 32
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 24
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 32
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi vnmi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer posted_intr invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority apicv tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest vapic_reg vid ple shadow_vmcs ept_mode_based_exec tsc_scaling usr_wait_pause
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs eibrs_pbrsb
bogomips    : 4838.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

cat cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
5400000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
4000000
5400000
4000000
4000000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
5400000
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. It was actually caused by my use of cpupower-gui. Rebooting the machine restores the correct values for each core. Apparently with this CPU not all P-cores are allowed to reach 5.6 GHz, some are still limited to 5.4 GHz.

```
$ find /sys/devices -name scaling_max_freq | sort -V | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {} && cat {}'
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy6/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy7/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy8/scaling_max_freq
5600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy9/scaling_max_freq
5600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy10/scaling_max_freq
5600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy11/scaling_max_freq
5600000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy12/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy13/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy14/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy15/scaling_max_freq
5400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy16/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy17/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy18/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy19/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy20/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy21/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy22/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy23/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy24/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy25/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy26/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy27/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy28/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy29/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy30/scaling_max_freq
4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy31/scaling_max_freq
4000000
```

So when I use the cpupower-gui tool to change the governor or max cpu frequency and select the "all cpus" option it will modify the frequency of all the CPUs but based on the limits of the select CPU core which is the first core by default. In this case that first core is 5.4 GHz max so then it ends up setting all cores to 5.4 GHz max, the e-cores end up being limited to 4 GHz and the 5.6 GHz p-cores are forced down to 5.4 GHz. The solution is first select core 8 or one of the other cores capable of running at 5.6 GHz and using the all CPUs option to in the GUI to modify the governor or adjust/restore max speed.